# Socket library file.get(char) takes the first character of the file, sends it and then the rest of the file

Tags: c++, sockets

Im trying out socket library. I'm opening a file with content in it and then sending the content character by character to the server so it can write it to another file.

heres part of my client code

```
    char fileName[128];
    char quit[5] = "quit";
    ofs << "Enter the file name to transmit" << std::endl;
    cout << "Enter the file name to transmit" << std::endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    if (strcmp(fileName, "quit") == 0) {
        send(ClientSocket, quit, sizeof(quit), 0);
        break;
    }

    ifstream myFile(fileName);
    if (myFile.fail()) {
        ofs << "File could not be opened." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "File could not be opened." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        char TxBuffer;
        while (myFile.get(TxBuffer)) {
            send(ClientSocket, &TxBuffer, sizeof(TxBuffer), 0);
        }
    }
```

And then the server code corresponding to it

```
        while (1) {
        char RxBuffer[500] = {};
        recv(ConnectionSocket, RxBuffer, sizeof(RxBuffer), 0);

        if (strcmp(RxBuffer, "quit") == 0)
            break;

        std::ofstream myFile("temp.txt");
        if (myFile.fail()) {
            cout << "Error: could not openn temp.txt" << endl;
        }
        else
            myFile.flush();
            myFile << RxBuffer;
        myFile.close();

        cout << "Msg Rx: "<< RxBuffer << endl;
```

so if the file says video games
the server outputs:
v
ideo games

and the file is just ideo games

my question is how do I fix the output so that it outputs the complete file in one line

Comment: Do you have a specific problem and question?  This website's not for general code reviews... (there's a dedicated [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website).

Comment: Yea sorry, I just wanted to know if there was a way to not have it output like that but output it completely

Comment: Well, your server's `while (1)` loop recreates the file from scratch each time `recv()` returns more data.  You should append to the file instead.  What's probably happening is the first loop iteration's receiving the "v", writing that to the file, then the second loop iteration's receiving "ideo games" and overwriting the file just with that.

Comment: I thought about that. But when I send a different file, I want the contents of the old file deleted so it's just the new one

Comment: Then you'll need to create a *protocol* for the client-server interactions that supports that.  The easiest one is for the client to close the socket and re-open it when sending a different file.  Another option is to extend your existing protocol (wherein "quit" is supposed to make the server terminate), with another message like "erase_file").  That said, your current "quit" thing isn't implemented properly.  You shouldn't expect the received data to be grouped the same way it was when sent: TCP is a *byte steam* protocol - you should google that and understand it.